# Cannot load Tensorflow LSTM model implementing RSquare metric from TFA

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm running Python 3.8.10 and Tensorflow 2.3.0, installed with `conda`, and Tensorflow Addons v.0.13.0, installed via pip (because the latest version available on conda is 0.9.1). These versions *should* be compatible, according to the [compatibility matrix](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons#python-op-compatibility-matrix) on the Tensorflow Addons GitHub README file.

I have created a set of LSTM models and saved them as TF models, like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

n_lstm_cells = [5, 10, 20, 50, 100]
models = []

for cells in n_lstm_cells:
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(units = cells))
  model.add(Dense(units = 182))
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = [tfa.metrics.RSquare(y_shape = (182,))])
    
  os.makedirs(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\stefa\Documents\models\Case A\checkpoints\LSTM",f"{cells} cells"), exist_ok = True) 
  checkdir = os.path.join(r"C:\Users\stefa\Documents\models\Case A\checkpoints\LSTM",f"{cells} cells",'noDST-log1p-{epoch:02d}-{val_r_square:.3f}.hdf5')
  callbacks = [ModelCheckpoint(checkdir, save_freq='epoch', save_best_only = True, monitor = 'val_r_square', mode = 'max'),
             EarlyStopping(patience = 10)]
  print(f'Fitting model with {cells} cells')
  history = model.fit(train_data_gen, epochs = 500, validation_data = val_data_gen, callbacks = callbacks)
  models.append(history)

for cells, model in zip(n_lstm_cells, models):
    os.makedirs(r'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\models\Case A\LSTM\noDST-singlestep-24h-LSTM-{}'.format(cells), exist_ok = True)
    model.model.save(r'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\models\Case A\LSTM\noDST-singlestep-24h-LSTM-{}'.format(cells))
```

When I try to load it, however, I get a "ValueError: Unable to restore custom object of type _tf_keras_metric currently. Please make sure that the layer implements `get_config`and `from_config` when saving. In addition, please use the `custom_objects` arg when calling `load_model()`, even though I am passing r_square as custom metric.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
lstm_model = load_model(r'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\models\Case A\LSTM\noDST-singlestep-24h-LSTM-100', custom_objects = {'r_square': tfa.metrics.RSquare})
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost right just use `RSquare` instead of `r_square`

```
lstm_model = load_model(r'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\models\Case A\LSTM\noDST-singlestep-24h-LSTM-100', custom_objects = {'RSquare': tfa.metrics.RSquare})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that saved me a lot of headache!